# Disable hover effect, but keep on click function

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

This is my first time on stackverflow and hope someone could help me with this kind of problem.

I made website in Wordpress and want to disable hover effect on my category list in webshop. There are parent categories which automatically, when you hover with mouse, dropdown child categories. After researching i found css solution which looks like this:

```
.widget.woocommerce.widget_product_categories ul li{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Wordpress Customize Custom CSS,
[image: screenshot]

After this kind of update i found the problem - when i click on parent category, nothing happens (because of pointer-events obviously).

Is there any CSS solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: Yes, pointer-events just disable the events made by the point/mouse pointer like click events.

To disable the dropdown, you can just use this:

.widget.woocommerce.widget_product_categories ul li > ul {
    display: none !important;
}

Comment: @CarlOrtiz thank you for your comment Carl! Unfortunately, this isn't what i want. Hover effect is disabled now, but dropdown of child categories isn't showing. I can't see child categories :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello did you try the following, I think you can use the CSS to just disable to pointer event on hover:

```css
.widget.woocommerce.widget_product_categories ul li:hover {
pointer-events: none;
}
```

Edit 1:

ok the functionality that you need can't be done with CSS alone, you will need a bit of Javascript.

Try to add the following code in theme javascript file

```
jQuery(".cat-item.cat-parent > a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const ul_children = jQuery(this).parent().find('> ul.children');
  if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('open')
    ul_children.css('max-height',0)
  } else {
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('open');
    ul_children.css('max-height', ul_children[0].scrollHeight )
  }
  
})
```

also add the following CSS:

```
 .product-categories > .cat-parent:hover > ul.children {
    max-height: 0px;
    
}
.product-categories li ul.children li:hover > .children {
  max-height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gaby, i tried :hover and add pointer-events:none. What happens is that hover is disabled, but when i click on parent category, dropdown isn't showing (nothing happens) :(

Comment: HI @ŽeljkoRonta can you share the website link so I can check it for you?

Comment: thank you for your comment. I put this code in function.php and got error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Think it is because of: .click(function(event){ and at the end it is ')'

Comment: No you should not put this code in a php file, it should be added in a JS file inside your active theme, if you don't know how to do it, tell me and I will try to assist you

Comment: no Gaby. Client just provided cpanel informations so i can properly search js file. Is there specific js file or i can put this code in any js file?

Comment: try to add them in this file `wp-content/themes/ambient-child/navigacijaOpen.js`

Comment: succesfully added in navigacijaOpen.js and added css code, but nothing happens :S

Comment: are you sure I checked the file and it seems that you still have the old code there https://www.akord-zupanja.hr/wp-content/themes/ambient-child/navigacijaOpen.js?ver=1.1

Comment: Gaby, it's working! I had to hard reset page to see the update. Thank you a lot for help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this code

```
.cat-parent:hover > ul.children {
    max-height: 373px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

by this one

```
.cat-parent:active > ul.children {
    max-height: 373px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The only step left is to remove the link from your parent category. If you do not remove this link, it will redirect you automatically when you click on it

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work :S I changed ":hover" to ":active" in style.css theme file and nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0):

Simply we can hide container when in hover effect by Jquery such as

```
 // remove popup on hover for mini cart dawar
   $(".icon").hover(function(){
        $("#container").css("display", "none");
    });
```